# Populating a tilemap with setTile method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a method to randomly populate a tile map with specific tiles when called, but what I've written so far does not work and does not produce any errors either. Here's my class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class PopulateMap : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Tilemap map; //tilemap that needs to be populated
    public Tile tile1; //tiles that are used to populate map
    public Tile tile2;
    public Tile tile3;
    public Tile tile4;
    public Tile tile5;
    public Tile tileNull; //blank tile used to draw base map, gets replaced with tiles 1-5
    List<Vector3> tileLocations; //list to store the locations of the tiles

    int arrayPos = 0; //used for array index

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var cellBounds = map.cellBounds.allPositionsWithin;
        tileLocations = new List<Vector3>();
    

        foreach (var pos in map.cellBounds.allPositionsWithin) //stores all tile locations into a list
        {
            Vector3Int localPlace = new Vector3Int(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
            Vector3 place = map.CellToWorld(localPlace);
            if (map.HasTile(localPlace))
            {
                tileLocations.Add(place);
            }
        }

        FillMap();

    }

    void FillMap()
    {
        arrayPos = 0;

        foreach (Vector3 n in tileLocations)
        {
            float f = Random.Range(0.1f, 1.0f);
        
            if (f < 0.2f)
            {
                map.SetTile(Vector3Int.FloorToInt(tileLocations[arrayPos]), tile1);
            } else if (f < 0.3f)
            {
                map.SetTile(Vector3Int.FloorToInt(tileLocations[arrayPos]), tile2);
            } else if (f < 0.4f)
            {
                map.SetTile(Vector3Int.FloorToInt(tileLocations[arrayPos]), tile3);
            } else if (f < 0.5f)
            {
                map.SetTile(Vector3Int.FloorToInt(tileLocations[arrayPos]), tile4);
            } else if (f < 0.6f)
            {
                map.SetTile(Vector3Int.FloorToInt(tileLocations[arrayPos]), tile5);
            } else
            {
                map.SetTile(Vector3Int.FloorToInt(tileLocations[arrayPos]), null);
            }

            arrayPos++;
        }
    }   
}
```

Not sure why the method isn't working as when I print out any of the data from the list it gives me the coordinates of the tiles. As I don't want to populate the entire tilemap, I've used the nullTile in the editor to draw the area that I want the code to affect.

[image]

If anyone could point out what I've messed up, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think you have to use the `CellToWorld` for the `SetTile` parameter?

[`SetTile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.SetTile.html)

> Sets a tile at the given XYZ **coordinates of a cell in the tile map**.

and expects as parameter

> **`Vector3Int` position**
>
> Position of the `Tile` **on the `Tilemap`**.

You simply want to rather use the position without any conversion at all!
I would then refactor your code a bit like this:

```
public Tilemap map; //tilemap that needs to be populated
public Tile tile1; //tiles that are used to populate map
public Tile tile2;
public Tile tile3;
public Tile tile4;
public Tile tile5;
public Tile tileNull; //blank tile used to draw base map, gets replaced with tiles 1-5

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    var cellBounds = map.cellBounds.allPositionsWithin;

    var positions = new List<Vector3Int>();

    foreach (var position in cellBounds)
    {
        // without any conversion directly use the position which already
        // IS the grid index inside the map
        if (map.HasTile(position))
        {
            positions.Add(position);
        }
    }

    // pass them on as parameter so you don't need any class field for this
    FillMap(positions);
}

private void FillMap(List<Vector3Int> positions)
{
    // go through all positions directly
    // foreach already gives you each element so directly use it
    // instead of accessing it twice via an index
    foreach (var position in positions)
    {
        // again directly without any rounding use the position that already is the Vector3Int you need
        map.SetTile(position, GetRandomTile());
    }
}

// to clean things up again separate the random tiles into a dedicated method
private Tile GetRandomTile()
{
    // This basically equals "Random.Range(0f, 1f)" but is shorter ;)
    var f = Random.value;

    if (f < 0.2f)
    {
        return tile1;
    }

    if (f < 0.3f)
    {
        return tile2;
    }

    if (f < 0.4f)
    {
        return tile3;
    }

    if (f < 0.5f)
    {
        return tile4;
    }

    if (f < 0.6f)
    {
        return tile5;
    }

    return tileNull;
}
```

Comment: Code works beautifully so thank you for the help. As for why I thought I needed to use cellToWorld, it's quite simple... I'm dumb :D. Also you made a small typo when you refactored my code in the FillMap method you left the vector3int as n instead of position.

Comment: @Aironas oh yeah fixed the typo, typed this on the phone and din't note ^^ And nah you're not dumb ;) We all make this type off misassumption from time to time